# How to add a concrete reference to the classpath in Eclipse project by gradle?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse, build.gradle, eclipse-classpath

All examples that I see in the documentaton, that tell how to add an entry to the Eclipse project classpath by build.gradle file are too common. They say nothing how to add an entry:

```
<classpathentry exported="true", kind="con" path="GROOVY_SUPPORT"/>
```

[Doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html) or the book "Gradle Effective Implementation Guide" are quite useless with advices as

```
  //closure executed after .classpath content is loaded from existing file
  //and after gradle build information is merged
  whenMerged { classpath ->
    //you can tinker with the Classpath here
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another classpath entry by creating an instance of [org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.Container](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/plugins/ide/eclipse/model/Container.html):

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged { classpath ->
                def groovySupportContainer = new org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.Container('GROOVY_SUPPORT')
                groovySupportContainer.exported = true
                classpath.entries << groovySupportContainer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks.( I found how to change it through 'withXml', but I wanted to know how to work with classpath directly). Could you also kindly say, WHERE have you got that info? I couldn't find it. :-(

Comment: I don't think it's really documented with a concrete example. I had a look at the Gradle Javadocs.

Comment: I have tried it, too, but if there is how to connect container to the classpath, I found nothing about how the container should be filled. Could you give me a reference, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "how the container should be filled"? Do you mean the classpath entries?

Comment: My mistake in explanation, sorry. When I read the docs, there was info on how to take classpath info from 'configuration' (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html). And you have shown me that it has to be done through 'container'. And the second important piece - that 'GROOVY_SUPPORT' - Where have you taken this? (When working directly with XML, I took the parameters needed by comparison with what the Eclipse writes into .classpath when I set groovy nature by hand)

Comment: I just took it from your question. That's all.

Comment: But how do you know that classpath entry "classpathentry exported="true", kind="con" path="GROOVY_SUPPORT" demands "Container('GROOVY_SUPPORT')"?